# Exit nohup alias after completion

Tags: bash, alias, nohup

I have a simple bash function which starts a python script using nohup. It looks something like this:

```
my_function(){
    printf 'Starting Python script.'
    nohup python my_script.py > log.out 2>&1
}
```

In the terminal I then do:

```
>>> my_function
Starting Python script.
```

The cursor then just keeps blinking behind the `.... script.` and I can not enter new commands into the terminal. Ctrl + C just terminates the script, but when I close the SSH connection it keeps on running.

Is there some kind of return statement I should put at the end of the function, such that I can enter commands again in the terminal?

Comment: By the way, `my_alias` is a function, not an alias.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, but in the link it doesn't say how to return to the terminal after executing the function right? Or is that where the `&` at the end is for?

Comment: I mean, you could just try it. Run `sleep 5 &` and see what happens. :-)

Comment: Thanks that solved it. You want to make it into an answer? It is not clearly explained in the link what the `&` does at the end.

Comment: It's in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists

Comment: Yes, but it would be good to have it here as well right? Plus then you get some internet points.

Comment: I don't know, this seems more like a "how do I use bash?" and less like a programming question.